# Flutter listview horizontal + new line

Tags: android, android-layout, flutter

I want to implement a horizontal listview in Flutter, but not scrollable. I need it to continue on a new row when the space runs out in the horizontal direction. So far I've only got

```
 return ListView.separated(
                separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                    const Divider(),
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ItemCard(items[index]);
                },
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemCount: items.length);
```

Comment: why not try grid view?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this case, you should try Wrap widget in flutter. By default, it will wrap in horizontal direction but if you want to wrap vertically then you can set direction.

```
Wrap(
  direction: Axis.vertical,
  children: [
    MyWidget(),
    MyWidget(),
    MyWidget(),
    MyWidget(),
    MyWidget(),
  ],
),
```

With row and column, if there is not enough space then we get the yellow and black overflow warning. But Wrap creates a new adjacent in the respective directive. This will complete your list view requirement.

There are many other options available which you can check [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html).

Answer (score 2):

set property physics in Listview.separated to make the listview not scrollable
And also you need to set the width of the ItemCard() widget

```
return ListView.separated(physics: NeverScrollablePhysics(),

                separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                    const Divider(),
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Container(
                    width: //your width size,
                    ItemCard(items[index])
                   );
                },
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemCount: items.length);
```